# playframework scala typemismatch while returning a seq

Tags: scala, playframework

I have actually a problem while returning a Seq back to frontend.

My code looks like this:

```
def getContentComponentsForProcessSteps: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    println("-----------------------------------------------New Request--------------------------------------------------------")
    println(request.body.asJson)
    request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[ProcessStepIds] match {
      case JsSuccess(steps, _) =>

        val contentComponents: Seq[Future[Seq[Future[ContentComponentModel]]]] = steps.steps.map(stepId => { //foreach
          // Fetching all ContentComponent Relations
          contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentsByStepId(stepId).map(contentComponents => { // Future[Seq[ContentComponent_ProcessStepTemplateModel]]
            // Iteration über die Gefundenen Relations
            contentComponents.map(contentComponent => { // foreach
              // Fetch Content Component
              contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentById(contentComponent.contentComponent_id).flatMap(contentComponent => { // Future[Option[ContentComponentModel]]
                // Fetch Content Component Data for the types
                val res = getContentComponentDataforOneContentComponent(contentComponent.get)
                res.map(con => con)
              })
            })
          })
        })

        Future.sequence(contentComponents).map(eins => {
          println(eins)
            Ok(Json.obj("Content Components Return" -> "true", "result" -> eins))
        })

      case JsError(_) =>
        Future.successful {
          BadRequest("Can't fetch Content Components")
        }
      case _ => Future.successful {
        BadRequest("Can't fetch Content Components")
      }
    }).getOrElse(Future.successful {
      BadRequest("Can't fetch Content Components")
    })
  }
```

Error is the following.

[image]

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the type of `eins` your error message is telling you that it is a `Seq[Seq[Future[ContenetComponentModel]]]` and not simply a `Seq` like you thought.

There are two problems with this:

1. You can't write a `Future` (or in your case, a sequence of futures) to Json.
2. You need to have an implicit function in scope to convert your `ContenetComponentModel` to a JSON value.

Depending on what you want your result to look like, you could try flattening `eins` and then using another `Future.sequence`, but I think what you really should be doing is changing a lot of your `.map` calls to `.flatMap` calls to avoid the nesting in the first place.